# Translation: 前期编排

Tags: translation, meaning

前期编排

**前期**

> pre-

or

> first-phase

**编排**

> write and present

or

> arrange and rehearse

or

> write and direct

or

> compose

Pre-composition?

First-phase-composition?

Can't find the official English equivalent of this.

Should be a film(ing) phrase.

---

My best guess is: pre-production

I think it's the opposite of 后期制作, which is **post-production**, so I think it has to be **pre-production** - Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say

> 前期
>   preliminary 
>   编排
>   arrangement

therefore, **preliminary arrangements**, which is what **pre-production** means. 
However I'm no film-making expert so maybe someone could double check this.

Comment: Confirms suspicions.